# EditText filed wont Behave accordingly

Tags: java, android, android-layout, mobile

I have 9 Edittext fields to work with. But their is a problem. I set the Edittext fields accordingly but when I run this application on emulator the fields reset them self automatically ( They are not remain at the place where i set them ).And when i run the apk on my mobile (sumsang y S 5360) they look even worse. Here is a Xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/zmal"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText,TextFields" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/showz"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:fontFamily="bold"
    android:textColor="#fefdfd"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/calc"
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="45dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/calbu"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/zktmal3"
android:layout_width="40dip"
android:layout_height="20dip"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/zktmal2"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:ems="10"
android:padding="3dp"
android:inputType="number"
android:textSize="12sp" >

<requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/zktmal5"
android:layout_width="40dip"
android:layout_height="20dip"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:ems="10"
android:padding="3dp"
 android:inputType="number"
android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/zktmal8"
android:layout_width="40dip"
android:layout_height="20dip"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/zktmal6"
android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
android:ems="10"
android:padding="3dp"
 android:inputType="number"
android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/zktmal9"
android:layout_width="40dip"
android:layout_height="20dip"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/zktmal8"
android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
android:ems="10"
android:padding="3dp" 
 android:inputType="number"
android:textSize="12sp"/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/zktmal10"
android:layout_width="40dip"
android:layout_height="20dip"
android:layout_above="@+id/calc"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
android:ems="10"
android:padding="3dp"
 android:inputType="number"
android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/zktmal1"
android:layout_width="40dip"
android:layout_height="20dip"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="number"
android:padding="3dp"
android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/zktmal4"
android:layout_width="40dip"
android:layout_height="20dip"
android:layout_above="@+id/zktmal5"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="number"
android:padding="3dp"
android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/zktmal2"
android:layout_width="40dip"
android:layout_height="20dip"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/zktmal1"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="number"
android:padding="3dp"
android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/zktmal6"
android:layout_width="40dip"
android:layout_height="20dip"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/zktmal5"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="number"
android:padding="3dp"
android:textSize="12sp" />



</RelativeLayout
```

Here is screenshot
http://postimg.org/image/6yf04lx6h/

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/6yf04lx6h/ screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use linearlayout and orientation:horizontal for each row:

And use a general relative layout for scroll view.

like this

```
<ScroolView>
<RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout />
<LinearLAyout />
<LinearLayout />
.
.
</RelativeLAyout>
<ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show how you layout the TextViews in your XML post but it is clear that they are very verbose.  When you have such a long TextView to caption an EditText, it would be better to just put the EditText on the next line.

If I were you, I would just have a scrolling layout like so:

```
<ScrollView>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/label1"/>
  <EditText> android:id="@+id/edit1"/>
  ...
  ...
  <TextView android:id="@+id/labelN"/>
  <EditText android:id="@+id/editN"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I thought scrollview can only have 1 child? like textview is consider as 1 child..